# Container for 2 values (for each float number one manipulatable integer)

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, double, containers

I need to contain integers for several(n) different float values.

- for example: for float number 1,465658 I need to contain number 1 and I need to be able to manipulate
  the integer number at any time.

Is there some container for it in C++ or do I have to do some multidimensional array(if yes which)?

something like: float[1,465658]=3;
new float[1,98978]=0;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::map`? As long as your keys are unique.

```
std::map<double, int> myMap;
myMap[1.2465468] = 1;
```

Be aware that you may encounter some floating point rounding imprecision depending on the granularity of your values, and you may end up overwriting existing entries.

Comment: It sounds very scary to me to use a floating point number for a key in a `map`.

Comment: Why is it scary? As long as you don't put any NaN values in the map it will work just fine.

Comment: I'd expect more of the other way, you insert a new key although you would have wanted to manipulate an existing entry.

Comment: Yeah.. The multimap is essentially useless, and you can't really defeat any issues of precision doing it. You'll end up mapping multiple integers to the same double. I have edited my answer.

Comment: @DanielFischer - Yeah of course, my comment came out wrong. I share the same point as Kiril and yourself.